# no crash if I reset the same shared_ptr in multi-threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, smart-pointers

I just want to confirm it's safe to reset to the same smart pointer with lock in multi-threads? if there is no lock_guard, it's not safe due to it is not a thread-safe method? I suppose reset is not threadsafe, however, no crash is observed if I removed the lock.

```
class foo {
public:
   foo()
   {
       std::cout << "foo constructed" << std::endl;
   }
   ~foo()
   {
       std::cout << "foo destructed" << std::endl;
   }
};
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::shared_ptr<foo> f = std::make_shared<foo>();
    conqueue = dispatch_queue_create("MyConcurrentDiapatchQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    static std::mutex io_mutex;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        dispatch_async(conqueue, ^{

            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(io_mutex); // no crash without this line as well
            f.reset(); // it's safe? No crash if I reset the same shared_ptr in multi-threads.
        });
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you know what `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(io_mutex);` does? You used  Objectve-C closure though

Comment: Yes, it attempts to take ownership of the mutex it is given. When control leaves the scope in which the lock_guard object was created, the lock_guard is destructed and the mutex is released, I intentionally add this lock to test. I suppose reset is not threadsafe, however, no crash is observed if I removed the lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shared_ptr` object is not thread-safe, nor is the pointed-to object. Only the reference count is thread-safe. So yes, you need to use a guard.

In C++20, there is `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>`.

Comment: Thanks, krisz. It's safe to reset the same shared_ptr multiple times without multithreading, right? the implementation of reset should have some checks?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation don't guarantee safety of that component. Essentially if standard says nothing about it then your assumption is right. You have to have that lockquard or anything that provides same functionality.

Crash might be no observable because you don't have racing condition until you try read pointer in a concurrent thread because you don't actually try to use that value (all that reset does is to change pointer value).

Well and you can't rely on that you can't observe an UB, UB is a Schrodinger's cat.

Comment: Thanks, Firday Pie for your info.